# Dropdown menu não mostra subitens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Já vi várias postagens, todas com várias respostas, mas não consigo colocar meu dropdown para funcionar no menu. Ele simplesmente não abre. Será que preciso instalar algo a mais?

Meu código é esse:

```
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>         
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
```

Estou usando o typescript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Testei aqui e esta funcionando perfeitamente, verifique se os arquivos do bootstrap estão sendo incluídos corretamente no head do seu código.

segue o exemplo:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste</title>

    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
          <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Page 1
                  <span class="caret"></span></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Page 1-3</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </li>         
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>

    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Boa tarde Daniel, continua não funcionando. Estou achando que deve estar faltando algo. Suspeito de alguma configuração que eu não tenha feito, afinal, sou bem iniciante no assunto.

Comment: Boa tarde, faça o seguinte copie este código inteiro e cole no seu editor, salve como teste.html e abra-o no seu navegador. Caso funcione verifique os arquivos do bootstrap que você incluiu no seu projeto, eles podem ser incluidos via CDN que é a forma que eu lhe passei acima ou você pode baixar os arquivos e inclui-los manualmente nas pastas do seu projeto.
Aqui tem um link de como você pode inclui-los corretamente:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_get_started.asp

Aqui um link com exemplos de dropdowns e navbars:

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_navbar.asp

Comment: Daniel, criei a página teste.html e funcionou.
Eu acho que meu problema é que estou usando o ng server em ambiente de desenvolvimento. Por que digo isso? Fiz a alteração que você posou, salvei e o servidor recompilou o arquivo e atualizou a página com o menu, porém, "lá" no localhost/4200 ele não funciona. Será que falta alguma coisa no meu ambiente de desenvolvimento?

Comment: Provavelmente, tente verificar nas pastas do seu projeto se está tudo ok com os links, se não os inclua ou os corrija. Se mesmo assim não funcionar tente baixar os arquivos do bootstrap e coloca-los dentro do repositório do seu projeto, então os inclua diretamente pelo nome dos arquivos.

Comment: Daniel, esse é o problema. Não sei ver ainda se está tudo OK e quais arquivos colocar dentro do repositório e em qual repositório. Mas sua dica valeu muito. Já vou avançar para outro nível do meu problema. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O download fica aqui: http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download . se você preferir pode instalar o bootstrap 4 mais ainda esta em desenvolvimento. Você poderia tbm instala-lo via npm, já que trabalha com um ambiente dev. Para instala-lo manualmente vc tem que ir dentro das pastas do seu projeto, colar os arquivos que vc baixou e chama-los dentro do arquivo principal ou só no arquivo atual para testar. Existem diversos guias de como fazer isso pela internet, inclusive pelo próprio site do bootstrap. Se houver qualquer dificuldade a mais estou a disposição.

Comment: Eu já instalei via npm. Acho que falta alguma referência em algum lugar. Algo que tenho que fazer a mais para funcionar.